# MATE - Language swtiching using shortcut stops once it reaches the last language in the list

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate, language-support

I had 3 languages (EN, RU, HE) which were switched by win+space and everything worked fine. Now I have added SK to the list, and once the cycle comes to SK it never continues to the start of the list, while this works perfectly with alt+shift. I guess something is wrong with win key on Slovak layout, could you please give some directions on how to fix this?
Attached layout configuration. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, MATE 1.20.1

[image]

Comment: if you add `shift` does it move back up the list?

Comment: @tatsu No, still stays in Slovak

Comment: well shucks. guess this is a big one. the solution will eiher involve scripting or editing the non binary files of keyboard prefs.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. Please inform the MATE developers about the problem by writing post on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> set as keyboard layout switching hotkey - the

```
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options \
"['grp\tgrp:win_space_toggle']"

dconf write /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts \
"['us', 'ru', 'il', 'sk']"
```

results in the behavior that I can move from 'sk' to 'us' again.

So I have reported [bug 1821988](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-control-center/+bug/1821988) to launchpad.

Consider to use workaround - use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> instead.

Comment: Thank you sir for doing the bureaucracy for me. I close this question, for now.